# How to calculate element's width and height with their padding / margin values using less code?

Tags: jquery, css, height, width

I am using [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) / [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method but its returning value without it's padding and margin values. I am not having problem to calculate total with / height values.

This way is working but my problem is; its too long to calculate all of them. Is there a way to calculate these with less code without bugs ?

[Here is jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/B7fMW/6/)

jQuery:

```
var ele = $('div');

var eleW = ele.width();
var eleH = ele.height();

alert(eleW);//returning 200
alert(eleH);//returning 100

var eleMR = parseInt(ele.css('margin-right'));
var eleML = parseInt(ele.css('margin-left'));
var eleMT = parseInt(ele.css('margin-top'));
var eleMB = parseInt(ele.css('margin-bottom'));

var elePR = parseInt(ele.css('padding-right'));
var elePL = parseInt(ele.css('padding-left'));
var elePT = parseInt(ele.css('padding-top'));
var elePB = parseInt(ele.css('padding-bottom'));

var eleTotalWidth = eleMR + eleML + elePR + elePL + eleW;
var eleTotalHeight = eleMT + eleMB + elePT + elePB + eleW;

alert(eleTotalWidth);//returning 147
alert(eleTotalHeight);//returning 122
```

css:

```
div {
       float:left; width:100px; height:200px; background-color:#000;
       margin:5px 3px 2px 4px; padding:10px 20px 5px;
     }​
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`outerWidth();`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) and [`outerHeight();`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

```
var ele = $('div');

var eleW = ele.outerWidth(true);
var eleH = ele.outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B7fMW/7/ this is calculating without margins, but its still lesser code than mine (:

Comment: As per @WouterH we need to pass true as mentioned in the documentation. Pass true it will include your margin also.

Comment: @Vins: that makes your answer correct. I'll remove my answer as you was the first while I was still playing with the fiddle :)

Comment: and note that, this way also returns border values.

Comment: @Vins - great stuff. Thank you very much for posting that. Even though it was a while back, it came in very handy for me. Thanks.