# jquery: wrong values when trying to get div height

Tags: jquery, height

i'm having this html structure:

```
<div class=container>
    <div class=content>
            Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

i'm reading out the div.content height using:

```
var height = $("div.content").height();
```

will return 17 (in my testcase)

works nice so far (when comparing it with the actual height using firebug).
the problem is - when filling up continuous text >2 lines i'm getting a wrong value.
2 lines will give me 34 (correct) but 3 lines will also return 34 although the actual height is 51. of course, when filling in plenty of text the resulting value is all wrong.
seems like a jquery bug to me .. any ideas for a workaround?
thanks

ps: works perfect in IE, firefox returns a wrong value ..

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665657/how-to-calculate-elements-width-and-height-with-their-padding-margin-values-u

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use **`$("div.content").outerHeight();`** instead.

If you add -true- in the parenthesis if you want to include all margins & paddings as well.
`$('div.content').outerHeight(true);`

Also cross-browser heights may differ if you don't have very good **CSS Resets**, or are looking at a legacy browser (ie6/7), but with a good reset their differences will be very miniscule.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yz3B6/2/)

Comment: What "occurs"?  I get same results in Chrome/Firefox and IE.

Comment: Do you mean a discrepancy in the Height between browsers?

Comment: mcpDESIGNS: yes .. different values

Comment: Oh that's why you always need to have very detailed -reset- css style sheets, just updated the jsFiddle, they should be the same now (ie8 & firefox).

Comment: Thank you! Ipad was not getting the correct value without (true)

Comment: there is just one thing left: `<3` merci bro