# Unable to get the correct height of element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, height, directive

I've got a directive whos purpose is to set a child's height to be equal to the parent.

I **can not** use `height: inherit;` or `height: 100%;` for this.

The problem is that the `outerHeight(true)` returns the wrong height no matter what I do. The height that it returns it `175` when is should be closer to around `720`, which to me doesn't make any sense whatsoever..

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7TeTrw9RsTgR7mfzzDg0?p=preview, I didn't manage to get the directive to run in it though. Had the same issue in the jsFiddle, not sure what I'm doing wrong there but I hope someone knows how to fix it and can play around in it.

I've used `outerHeight()`, `outerHeight(true)`, `height()` and `.css('height')` but all of them returns `175` as the height.

**EDIT:** I even tried a third-party plugin that sets the columns as equal height, but that plugin also got the wrong height.

**EDIT 2:** I also found out that it is in fact working, but only after you've resized the window.. Is the directive being run before the element has gotten its height or something?

**EDIT 3:** I found a working solution but it's not optimal as it causes a delay of 200ms, therefore causing the element to jump down once it executes:

```
core.directive('heightInheritance', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      $timeout(function(){

        var parentHeight = element.parent().outerHeight(true);

        element.css('height', parentHeight + 'px');

        $(window).resize(function() {

          parentHeight = element.parent().outerHeight(true);

          element.css('height', parentHeight + 'px');

          console.log(element.parent().css('height'));
        });

      }, 200);
    }
  }
}]);
```

This solution came from here: [How can I run a directive after the dom has finished rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240639/how-can-i-run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering)

However, that suggests that you should do it without a delay, but as soon as I go under 200ms I get the same result as before. I figured I would cause a delay in the route itself but that did nothing to solve the issue either unfortunately. Is there any way I can remove the delay here?

I've looked at these questions:

[How to calculate element's width and height with their padding / margin values using less code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665657/how-to-calculate-elements-width-and-height-with-their-padding-margin-values-u)

[jquery: wrong values when trying to get div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184133/jquery-wrong-values-when-trying-to-get-div-height)

[jQuery height() returning false values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590482/jquery-height-returning-false-values)

But they all says the same thing basically, and their answers aren't working.

Here's my directive:

```
core.directive('heightInheritance', [function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var parentHeight = element.parent().outerHeight(true);

      element.css('height', parentHeight + 'px');
    }
  }
}]);
```

The height is based off an image which sets the height of the left column. By using Bootstrap's `row-eq-height` class it will make all the direct columns the same height. This is working correctly but now I need to make a `.row` inside of the right column to inherit the height of the right column.

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-2 hidden-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
    <img ng-src="somepath" class="image"> <!-- sets the height of the col -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div data-height-inheritance class="row"> <!-- need this to inherit height from parent -->
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
      <div data-height-inheritance class="col-sm-10"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could be causing this issue? I don't know what else to do here.

Comment: very interesting issue..will be looking at it whenever I'm on machine..

Comment: did you find anything on this?

Comment: @PankajParkar Nope, tried to write a directive which checks height on multiple things but the height always becomes incorrect. I'm not sure if bootstrap's grid system is what's causing it or if it's something else.

Comment: Seeing something similar. Were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: @AshD No idea. This was too long ago haha.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to just add a comment, but have you tried adding `style="overflow-y:hidden"` to the parent element prior to getting the height (you can reset it afterwards). I have had issues where the overflow affected the js height values.

Comment: Still, answers are **not** comments. So please don't use them to give comments.